# \boxed border color

Tags: math-mode, equations, color

I would like to change border color of an boxed equation (without disturb equation color); I'm using to boxing equations this code:

```
    \begin{equation*}
        \boxed{E_{F_i}-E_c = \frac{E_v-E_c}{2} +\frac{K_B T}{2}\log\left[ \frac{N_v}{N_c} \right]} 
    \end{equation*}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know whether this is possible. As far as I know `\boxed` uses `\fbox` and that's a `\hbox`, so the frame colour is fixed as soon all goes into the `\box` nirvana, so automatic changing back is not possible (or at least very difficult)

Comment: `\boxed` is just `\fbox` so simplest is perhaps {\color{red}\boxed{\color{black}]E_{..}}}`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following example defines `\colorboxed` as wrapper around `amsmath`'s `\boxed` to set the frame color. It uses package `xcolor` for the color support to save the current color `.` before changing the color for the frame. Inside the box, the previous saved color is restored. This avoids a white background of `\fcolorbox`, since there is no "transparent" color.

The macro also supports an optional argument for specifying the color model.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Definition of \boxed in amsmath.sty:
% \newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Syntax: \colorboxed[<color model>]{<color specification>}{<math formula>}
\newcommand*{\colorboxed}{}
\def\colorboxed#1#{%
  \colorboxedAux{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\colorboxedAux}[3]{%
  % #1: optional argument for color model
  % #2: color specification
  % #3: formula
  \begingroup
    \colorlet{cb@saved}{.}%
    \color#1{#2}%
    \boxed{%
      \color{cb@saved}%
      #3%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \boxed{
    E_{F_i}-E_c =
    \frac{E_v-E_c}{2} +
    \frac{K_B T}{2}\log\left[ \frac{N_v}{N_c} \right]
  }
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \colorboxed{red}{
    E_{F_i}-E_c =
    \frac{E_v-E_c}{2} +
    \frac{K_B T}{2}\log\left[ \frac{N_v}{N_c} \right]
  }
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \colorboxed[rgb]{0, 0, 1}{
    E_{F_i}-E_c =
    \frac{E_v-E_c}{2} +
    \frac{K_B T}{2}\log\left[ \frac{N_v}{N_c} \right]
  }
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Could you use `\colorboxedAux` in an example? What do you mean with "color model"?

Comment: `\colorboxedAux` is just an internal command. Another name would be `\@colorboxed`, but this naming scheme would require `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: So... if I define `\colorboxed` should I also define `\colorboxedAux`? Or could I define simply `\colorboxed` without it?

Comment: @JFernan Since `\colorboxed` uses `\colorboxedAux`, it will not work with an undefined `\colorboxedAux`. Thus, you need of course both definitions.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a way with `\color{}` change before and then switching back to the old colour which has been stored before with a `\colorlet{...}{.}` statement. The name `oldcolor` is arbitray, effectively, unless some other colorname should be overwritten.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
  \colorlet{oldcolor}{.}
  \color{blue}
  \boxed{\color{oldcolor}E_{F_i}-E_c = \frac{E_v-E_c}{2} +\frac{K_B T}{2}\log\left[ \frac{N_v}{N_c} \right]} 
\end{equation*}


{\color{brown}
\begin{equation*}
  \colorlet{oldcolor}{.}
  \color{blue}
  \boxed{\color{oldcolor}E_{F_i}-E_c = \frac{E_v-E_c}{2} +\frac{K_B T}{2}\log\left[ \frac{N_v}{N_c} \right]} 
\end{equation*}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatives: `empheq` or `tcolorbox` packages which provide other typesetting facilities

Answer (score 6):

The simplest is to use the `empheq` package, which is done for that. Needless to load `amsmath`, since it loads `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand\widecolourbox[1]{{\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}\setlength\fboxsep{8pt}\fcolorbox{DarkSeaGreen3}{white}{\enspace#1\enspace }}}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \boxed{
    E_{F_i}-E_c =
    \frac{E_v-E_c}{2} +
    \frac{K_B T}{2}\log\left[ \frac{N_v}{N_c} \right]}
\end{equation*}
\vspace{4ex}
\begin{empheq}[box =\widecolourbox]{equation*}
    E_{F_i}-E_c =
    \frac{E_v-E_c}{2} +
    \frac{K_B T}{2}\log\left[ \frac{N_v}{N_c} \right]
    \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to put the same ```widecolourbox``` just around a part of the equation?

Comment: @Ramanujan: Directly, I don't think so. You would have to copy the definition of `boxed{…}` to replace `\fbox`  with `\fcolorbox`, and place it by hand.