# Border color only on boxed equation

Tags: color, box

Starting from this question [\boxed border color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326375/boxed-border-color) I wanted to color only the box, but I also have number colored. Without to use `mdframed`, `tcolorbox`, or other package is there a very simple alternative (without macro) to have the color of the box? My MWE is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \colorlet{oldcolor}{.}
  \color{magenta}
  \boxed{\color{oldcolor}{F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just add `\color{oldcolor}` after the box, `\begin{equation}
  \colorlet{oldcolor}{.}
  \color{magenta}
  \boxed{\color{oldcolor} F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}\color{oldcolor}
\end{equation}`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No no :-((( a comment please. Put an answer thus I vote it. :)))) I have only 4 votes for today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, here's a version that uses `tcolorbox`'s `tcbhighmath` command:

[image: screenshot demonstrating the output using tcbhighmath]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    every box/.style={
            highlight math style={sharp corners,colback=white,colframe=magenta},
        }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \tcbhighmath{F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You might like to see Section 17.1 of the [tcolorbox documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for further reading; in particular, you might like to see `\tcboxmath`.

Comment: I always wish you and all those who give their knowledge to improve our society with little culture and respect.

Answer (score 6):

OK, per request. You most likely want to switch back to the normal color anyway, so

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \colorlet{oldcolor}{.}
  \color{magenta}
  \boxed{\color{oldcolor} F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}\color{oldcolor}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say that there are packages like `empheq`, `tcolorbox` and in particular the combination of the two which take care of these things automatically.

Answer (score 6):

I propose to define a `colorboxed` command, based on `\fcolorbox`, which has two mandatory argument – the colour of the frame  and the content of the frame, and the background of the frame as an optional argument:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\colorboxed}[3][white]{\fcolorbox{#2}{#1}{\m@th$\displaystyle#3$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \colorboxed{IndianRed}{F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \colorboxed[LavenderBlush!30]{IndianRed}{F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]