# how to make cellcolor not fill the cell completely

Tags: tables, color, makecell

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\makeatletter 
\def\l@subsubsection#1#2{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
    \circled{A}
    & \circled{B}
    & \circled{C}
          \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_1$} & \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_1$}   & \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_1$}          \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_2$}& \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_2$}    & \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_2$}  \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_3$}  & 
 \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_3$}   & \cellcolor{red!25}{p$_3$}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The above code creates the following table.
[image]

Is it possible to make the cell coloring not merge with the neighboring cells such that the text in the cell has the colored background but there is still some white spacing between the neighboring cells in both vertical and horizontal directions?

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: Here is a shorter solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  { custom-line = { command = TrimmedHline , 
                    tikz = {shorten < = 1pt, shorten > = 1.2pt} } , 
    custom-line = { letter = I , 
                    tikz = {shorten < = 1pt, shorten > = 1pt} } }

\begin{NiceTabular}{cIcIc}[cell-space-bottom-limit=2pt]
\CodeBefore
   \TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,fill=red!15}
   \rowcolor{white}{1}
\Body
  \circled{A} & \circled{B} & \circled{C} \\ \TrimmedHline
    p$_1$     & p$_1$       & p$_1$       \\ \TrimmedHline
    p$_2$     & p$_2$       & p$_2$       \\ \TrimmedHline
    p$_3$     & p$_3$       & p$_3$       \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

---

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[cell-space-limits=1mm]
\CodeBefore 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill [red!15] (2-|1) rectangle (5-|4) ; 
  \begin{scope} [color = white, line width = 2 pt]
    \draw (2-|1) -- (2-|4) (3-|1) -- (3-|4) (4-|1) -- (4-|4) ; 
    \draw (2-|2) -- (5-|2) (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ; 
  \end{scope}
  \draw (2-|1) -- (2-|4) (3-|1) -- (3-|4) (4-|1) -- (4-|4) ; 
  \draw (1-|2) -- (5-|2) (1-|3) -- (5-|3) ; 
  \draw [color = white, line width = 2 pt] (1-|1) rectangle (5-|4) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\Body
  \circled{A} & \circled{B} & \circled{C} \\
    p$_1$ & p$_1$ & p$_1$ \\
    p$_2$ & p$_2$ & p$_2$ \\
    p$_3$ & p$_3$ & p$_3$
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the second code]

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible ... to [have] some white spacing between the neighboring cells in both vertical and horizontal directions?

You could execute `\arrayrulecolor{white}` to achieve your typesetting objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
   \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\arrayrulewidth=2\arrayrulewidth % double the width of the rules

\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
    \circled{A} & \circled{B} & \circled{C} \\ 
    \hline
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{1} & 
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{1} & 
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{1} \\ 
    \hline
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{2} & 
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{2} & 
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{2} \\ 
    \hline
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{3} & 
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{3} & 
    \cellcolor{red!25}p\textsubscript{3} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better. But is it possible to have the white color on the sides of the red color patch in the cell but not lose the black lines between the cells?

Comment: @user25957 - In you initial posting, you mentioned "some white spacing between the neighboring cells", but didn't mention anything about keeping the black lines as well. Sorry for not picking up on that.

Answer (score 3):

Like this ?

[image]

With `tabularay`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = { *{3}c },
  hline{2-Y} = {1pt,solid},
  vline{2-Y} = {1pt,solid},
  row{2-Z} = {cmd=\colorbox{red!25}}
  }
  \circled{A} & \circled{B} & \circled{C}\\ 
  p$_1$ & p$_1$ & p$_1$ \\
  p$_2$ & p$_2$ & p$_2$ \\
  p$_3$ & p$_3$ & p$_3$ \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

EDIT : with `tabularray`, i think the answer of zarko is better (if you replace p1 by d1, \strut with \colorbox don't work).

Another solution with tikz

EDIT2: To make it look a little nicer, but unlike F. Pantigny's answer with `nicematrix`, you have to adjust the width of the rectangles manually, if the columns are not the same width.

[image]

**THE CODE:**

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

    \newcommand*\rect[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
    \node[inner sep=2pt,fill=red!25,minimum width=2em] (char) {\strut$#1$};}}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = { *{3}{Q[wd=2em,c]} },
    hline{2-Y} = {1pt,solid},
    vline{2-Y} = {1pt,solid},
    row{1} = {cmd=\circled},
    row{2-Z} = {cmd=\rect},
    rowsep=1pt,
    colsep=1pt
    }
    A & B & C\\ 
    p_1 & p_1  & d_1 \\
    p_2 & p_2  & d_2 \\
    p_3 & p_3  & d_3 \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of nice @pascal answer (+1):

- defined is command for coloring box behind cells content
- table body is in math mode

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{% <---- BEWARE
                        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\makeatletter   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522350/
    \newcommand{\cb}[3]{\fcolorbox{#2}{#1}{\m@th$\displaystyle#3$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hline{2-Y} = {1pt}, vline{2-Y} = {1pt},
             colspec = { *{3}{Q[c]} },
             colsep  = {2pt},
             row{2-Z}= {cmd=\cb{red!30}{red!30}}
            }
\circled{A} & \circled{B} & \circled{C}\\
  p_1 & p_1 & p_1 \\
  p_2 & p_2 & p_2 \\
  p_3 & p_3 & p_3 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your answer is better, if you replace p1 by d1, we can easily catch up with \strut in \fcolorbox{#2}{#1}{\strut\m@th$\displaystyle#3$}

Comment: @pascal974, both solution has drawback that size of cell contents should not differ. otherwise result is awful. This means, that we still need to digging for better solution ;-).